# Docker API, remote API, Client API

Tags: docker, docker-api

I would like to know when to use and the difference between Docker API, Docker remote API, Client API and Compose API. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only Docker Engine API, which allows you to manage Docker calling it.

Docker API = Docker Engine API

Docker remote API = I think this means to configure Docker CLI to connect to a remote API to manage container on other hosts.

Client API = Docker CLI. A CLI to use Docker Engine API.

Compose API = This doesn't exist, Compose is only a tool to use Docker Engine API.

For further information, check Docker Engine API docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

Answer (score 0):

**Basically all the categories that you are referring to are [Docker Engine APIs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/)**

As per the Docker Docs:

> The Engine API is the API served by Docker Engine. It allows you to
>   control every aspect of Docker from within your own applications,
>   build tools to manage and monitor applications running on Docker, and
>   even use it to build apps on Docker itself.
>
> It is the API the Docker client uses to communicate with the Engine,
>   so everything the Docker client can do can be done with the API. For
>   example:
>
> Running and managing containers Managing Swarm nodes and services
>   Reading logs and metrics Creating and managing Swarms Pulling and
>   managing images Managing networks and volumes

These APIs are used to control Docker on the remote servers.

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.

Answer (score -1):

> These APIs are used to control Docker on the remote servers.
>
> Docker Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.

Thanks, I was trying to understand the difference between the Docker APIs while working on [this Scalable Docker Deployment in the Bluemix platform](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/02/deploy-scalable-docker-application/).